# What if user starts begging for upvote on his question?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

The OP wrote: "Please upvote me, if my question is good."

Isn't this a bit weird?

Upvoting or downvoting a question shouldn't be prompted.

Isn't this looked down on? I feel this is very undignified.

It should be one's personal choice whether one likes the question and if they want to upvote the question right?

Comment: Outright begging for upvotes would trigger my itchy downvote finger. You should actually post a link to the question so it can be examined by others - or edit it yourself if you have sufficient rep (or suggest an edit if you don't).

Comment: I agree with slugster... I probably wouldn't be able to control my downvote finger either. I'm not sure that's the *right* thing to do (as Joachim questioned in a now-deleted comment), but it's probably what I *would* do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag the comment for Moderators attention...it is unwanted noise and not welcome.

**Edit**
As for wanting to be upvoted, that is the Community's decision...ironically, he's more likely to be discouraging people from upvoting his question with that behaviour.

Comment: but flagging the comment for Moderator's attention wont back fire on me if moderator finds it inappropriate for being flagged?? I am not sure on that so can you please tell m about it

Comment: @PARTH: No, flags cannot backfire on you. Having a flag rejected by a moderator won't affect your reputation in any way. And in this case, it's very unlikely that a moderator will disagree with you. Comments begging for upvotes are noise and should be deleted.

Comment: @PARTH now YOU are asking for your flag to be accepted?! Also "a bit weird", isn't it? [:-)

Comment: @Cody Gray: +1 to you. Thanks for sharing this. So nice of you to share your knowledge. :)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger: Where did I ask for my flag to get accepted? See everytime I answer a question on SO, I don't write something like "Please accept my answer and upvote it if you like it" and hence it is totally appropriate. Similar things I or community expects from a questioner as well. I hope that you understand this. :)

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger: I was just asking to davidsleeps whether flagging would backfire on me.

Comment: @PARTH maybe my English isn't that good - I just thought that `"so can you please tell m about it"` is kind of asking for it. There also is a smilley at the end of my comment - should be clear that it wasn't meant to be a **serious** comment.

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger: Ok I got it. It was no offense to you :) and as you said about "so can you please tell me aout it" is about asking to share the knowledge and not about asking for reputation points. Anyways thats fine :) Sorry if you found it offensive.

Comment: @ParthBhatt Flag such comments as "No longer needed", don't use a custom flag.